# XPath find a child node of a node with partial strings

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am using xpath via npm and I am searching for an XPath 1.0 expression, such that the search after 'name' and 'run' should result in the following output.

Finding the first "parent node" using "//*[contains(name(), 'name')]" already works, but I don't know if it's possible to find a child by a part of its name (any number of levels below)?

input:

```
<root>
    <NameX>
       <getLenght>
         <unit>m</unit>
       </getLenght>
       <getStatus>
         <status>0</status>
       </getStatus>
   </NameX>
   <Name2>
       <getStatus>
         <status>0</status>
       </getStatus>
       <running>
         <bit>true</bit>
       </running>
   </Name2>
</root>
```

output:

```
<running>
    <bit>true</bit>
</running>
```

Comment: Did you try `//*[contains(name(), 'name')]//*[contains(name(), 'run')]`?

Comment: I am not sure if i tried his already - i'll have a look on monday, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want your XPath to do?

Comment: @Andersson
I want to search in a tree and and with the result I want to create a tree structure in HTML, where the found values are shown as opened/highlighted. Therefore I want to be able to search for a parent node including 'name' and subnodes that include 'run' or 'getStatus', thus the output should be: 

'<getStatus> <status>0</status> </getStatus> <getStatus> <status>0</status> </getStatus> <running> <bit>true</bit> </running>'

Comment: Still confused... Do you want to get parent node based on its child node? SOmething like `//*[contains(name(), 'name') and .//*[contains(name(), 'run')]]`?

Comment: I want to get child nodes based on its parent node `//*[contains(name(), 'name)`. 

I'll then rebuild the tree structure with node.parentNode, which I get from XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andersson's answer is correct:

```
//*[contains(name(), 'name')]//*[contains(name(), 'run')]
```

**Advanced example:**

If you want to search for a parent node 'Name' which has at least a child element e.g. 'getLen' **or** getStat', then you can use this query:

```
//*[contains(name(), 'Name')]//*[contains(name(), 'getLen') or 
contains(name(), 'getStat')]`
```

output:

```
<NameX>
    <getLenght>
        <unit>m</unit>
    </getLenght>
    <getStatus>
        <status>0</status>
    </getStatus>
</NameX>
```